# Creating an asyncio Event in setUp() is a pitfall with aiounittest

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, python-asyncio, python-unittest

I'm using **aiounittest** for a unit test.
An object of the type **asyncio.Event()** is created in the **setUp()** method.
Awaiting for this object will lead to an *"RuntimeError ... got Future  attached to a different loop"*.

The cause of the problem seems to be that **aiounittest** creates a new event loop before executing the test, but after calling setUp.
Calling own setUp and tearDown directly from the test function will solve the problem. But this is not what i want.

Is it possible to create the Event with the correct event loop in setUp()?

Is there a alternative for **aiounittest** where **setUp()** and **tearDown()** with the correct event loop and support of being async ?

Here my test code:

```
import asyncio
import aiounittest


class TestAsyncioEvent(aiounittest.AsyncTestCase):

    async def trigger_event(self, event):
        await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
        event.set()

    def setUp(self):
        aiounittest.AsyncTestCase.setUp(self)
        self.event = asyncio.Event()

    async def test_event_wait(self):
        task = asyncio.create_task(self.trigger_event(self.event))
        await self.event.wait()
        await task
```

Comment: It is be better to use **asynctest.TestCase** instead of **aiounittest.AsyncTestCase**.
The **setUp** and **tearDown** functions can then be sync or async.
You can decorate your test function with **@asynctest.fail_on(active_handles=True)** to check for unfinished tasks.